# perforce admin To find out files is being submitted by user

Tags: perforce

I am a perforce admin. I am trying to find out files that is being submitted by perforce user.
I tried to read perforce.log and monitor tables but could not find these info.

I am trying to fetch this info just in case user is submitting files more than allowed limit in which he can block other perforce user jobs.

Any experience sharing on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd also have a look at the built-in performance gates on database access:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/07_perftune.html#1042633

These are easy to manage via settings in Perforce groups.

Taking a step back though, if you're worried about performance in general, I'd recommend having a chat with Perforce support.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to implement this sort of "site policy" in a Perforce installation: triggers, or a broker. You can write a submit trigger which can view the set of files that are about to be submitted, and reject the submit if it violates policy. You can also deploy a broker in front of your server, and have your broker command scripts implement your policy.

Perforce support can help you with these configuration tasks.

One observation, though: consider whether you really want to do this! From the description you've provided so far, it doesn't sound like a very useful policy (why are you trying to limit the amount of work your co-workers do? I want my co-workers to do as much work as they possibly can!)